# запрет на ввод неверных данных. python

Tags: python

Есть программа, которая принимает на вход некоторые числа и работает с ними. При вводе числа, начинающегося с 0 (например 001 и тд) программа продолжает работу, что и является ошибкой. Как прописать вывод ошибки и запрос на повторный ввод при вводе подобных данных?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Входные числа все целые?

Comment: Сложно ответить на вопрос без конкретики, но вообще, в таких случаях, то, что вводит пользователь, рассматривается вначале как строка и анализируется, а уже потом переводится, например в число.

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема только в потенциальных нулях в начале строки, то можно на входе сделать элементарную проверку, например:

```py
import re
s = input('Enter number')
if re.match(r'\d+', s):
    c = int(s)
    if c and s.startswith('0'):
        print('wrong format')
        # exit or repeat
    # continue
```